# NopCommerce Site to deploy from LocalHost

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

[image]

I am working in nopCommerce 3.90 and now my site is ready and I am unable to deploy it to an Azure Portal - what are the steps to do that? I was able to deploy it only web but getting issues in Database migration from local to Azure as shown in figure there is no any backup available or generate script?

Comment: I just wanted to copy db from local Sql to the azure server

Comment: In order to take backup from the Azure DB, you have to use option of [`Export a Data-tier Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017)